# Angular - Sidebar Nav list returns to home page

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12, I have this in my Nav sidebar component:

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">
    <i class="nav-icon fas fa-th"></i>
    <p>
      Settings
      <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
    </p>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/admin-dashboard/countries']" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
        <p>Countries</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/admin-dashboard/states']" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
        <p>States</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a [routerLink]="['/admin-dashboard/cities']" class="nav-link">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
        <p>Cities</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

When **Settings** is clicked, it supppose to dropdown and display these lists:

1. Countries
2. State
3. Cities

But rather, it returns to Home Page:

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show click method? Also you should remove  href="#" or just use href="javascript:void(0)"

Comment: Looks like you are using Bootstrap but not currectly. Take a look at this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content

Comment: @Bozhinovski - I don't have anything for the click. I just want it to display the sub-menus under it. I am using AdminLTE3 theme. When I added href="javascript:void(0)",  nothing is happening

Comment: I would agree with MajiD. This is bootstrap 4, and you are missing data-toggle from this. Check this one: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my quick stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ul-menu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

So basically, you need to have a click event bound to the Settings list-item to actually do something.

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span (click)="onSettingsClick()">Settings</span>
        <ul *ngIf="menuOpen">
          <li>Option 1</li>
          <li>Option 2</li>
          <li>Option 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  menuOpen = false;

  onSettingsClick(): void {
    this.menuOpen = !this.menuOpen;
  }
}
```

Comment: Am I now going to remove <a href="#" class="nav-link">

Comment: @user11352561 yes, remove <a> tag if you don't want to navigate anywhere from that text.